# How to modify Bootstrap carousel next/prev icons Thickness

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm starting to learn HTML/CSS and Bootstrap.

I have a carousel with the following next/prev buttons :

```
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="visually-hidden"> Previous </span>
</button>

<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="visually-hidden"> Next </span>
</button>
```

I would like to change the thickness of the buttons so I tried to add this code in my CSS stylesheet :

```
.carousel-control-prev {
    border-width: 35px;
}

.carousel-control-next {
    border-width: 35px;
}
```

I also tried :

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    border-width: 35px;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    border-width: 35px;
}
```

But this has no effect. Just to be clear, I am not trying to change the height/width of the buttons but the **thickness**. Do you have any idea how I could achieve this ?

Thank you !

Comment: have to tried the same with `!important` ??

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes I also tried that but it did not work. I guess I have to change the icon myself (w/ Font Awesome for instance) as pointed out by @Lecraminos in his answer.

Comment: you can use `box-sizing: border-box` on an element in order to have border width be a part of the overall width/height of the element. with the default box-sizing the border is in addition to the already set width/height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap v5 uses a pre-defined set of icons (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/extend/icons/). In earlier versions, it has been Glyphicons (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/). You may change the referenced icon within the set (if one suits you), the icon set itself (to e.g. Font Awesome, Material Design Icons, ...) or, if ambitious enough, create an own icon for that purpose that you link in with CSS.

According to the Bootstrap Manual you may also re-define the `$carousel-control-prev-icon-bg` and `$carousel-control-next-icon-bg` variables with whatever SVG data you prefer (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to change the icon using Font Awesome as an extra exercise :)